# Anyone know what this roof material can be made in blender 3d

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

[image]
This roof is bit confusing I don't understand whether it's a fabric or plastic or any other translucent material.

Comment: I am going to say not translucent because of the lack of change where the building is behind the end of it. But the shape and struts does indicate a non rigid material. Are you sure you want to use Blender-Render and not Cycles?

Comment: Actually I am new here so I don't know much about tags and I was not able to find blender cycles. Here I will use cycles. So please tell how make this material.

Comment: Depending on the level of detail required you should get away with the standard BSDF Diffuse and just playing with the Colour and Roughness. The difficult with recreating this scene will be the lighting. Investigate HDRI images that could provide what you need.